# How I can write the following stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have four tables in database.

- person(Perid ,firstname , lastname , gender)
- Research (Resid , Resname ,stareddate)
- person_research(Resid , Perid , others)
- Supervisors (Resid , Supervisorid , others)

I want to write stored procedure that returns each Research and Researcher Name and Supervisor Names  for put the results in datagridview.

Comment: What have you tried?  For what database?  This sounds like a job for rent-a-coder.com...

Comment: "I want to write stored procedure" - what's stopping you?

Comment: it would be great if you showed what you have tried as well as some sample data and your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for SQL server:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT R.resname as researchname
        , (p1.firstname + p1.lastname) as researcher
        , (p2.firstname + p2.lastname) as supervisor
    FROM Research R
    JOIN person_research PR
        ON R.Resid = PR.Resid
    JOIN person p1
        on PR.Perid = p1.Perid 
    JOIN supervisors s
        on R.Resid = s.Resid
    JOIN person p2
        on PR.Perid = p2.Perid 
END
GO
```

Comment: when the research have many supervisors the record of datagridview duplicates.can I merg two rows in one for the same research?

Comment: how do you know which supervisor you want?

Comment: Iam sorry but error message 'no aggregate funcation" appears

Comment: I removed the group by, how do you decide which supervisor you want if there are multiple?

Comment: can I merg the two supervisor names (name1 + name2) in same cell of datagridview for one research..thanks very much for helping me

Comment: I don't have time to rewrite it right now but you want to look at creating a comma separated list of values from multiple rows -search SO or here is a link http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/06/sql-server-creating-comma-separate-values-list-from-table-udf-sp/

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a DBMS so I'm assuming PostgreSQL:

```
create or replace function get_researchers()
  returns table(research_name, researchers, supervisors)
  language sql
AS
$body$
  select r.resname as research_name,
         string_agg(p.firstname||' '||p.lastname, ',') as researchers,
         string_agg(sp.firstname||' '||sp.lastname, ',') as supervisors
  from research r
    join person_research pr on pr.resid = r.resid
    join person p on pr.perid = p.perid,
    join supervisors s on s.resid = r.resid
    join person sp on sp.perid = s.perid
  group by r.resname
  order by r.resname;  
$body$
```